# 401 web exception while downloading file

Tags: c#, webclient, defaultproxy

I want to download a certain file from a website. For that, I tried using this

```
WebProxy p = new WebProxy("192.168.10.254:8080", true);
p.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = p;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("myDowloadUrl");
```

Each time, I get this web exception

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tested access from a browser?

Comment: Yep i could login using these credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to keep it simple always. Try this

```
       using (var Client = new WebClient())
        {
            Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");
            Client.DownloadFile("myDowloadUrl", @"downloadFilelocalpath");
        }
```

Comment: worked for me, but still when i try to unzip the downloaded file it says archive is either damaged or in unknown format

Comment: @user3108411 Perhaps the file is really damaged, make sure it's not damaged or try to download it through a browser.